# How do I make this script remove only one image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, forms

This script allows an image to be previewed / removed (by clicking on the image) before upload. The only issue I have is when I click on the image to remove it, it removes both of the images.

Form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
<input type="file" style="display:none" id="upload-image" multiple="multiple" name="upload[]"></input>
<div id="upload" class="drop-area">
   Upload File
</div>
<div id="thumbnail"></div>  
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" name="lesubmit"/>
</form>
```

Js:

```
jQuery(function($){
var fileDiv = document.getElementById("upload");
var fileInput = document.getElementById("upload-image");
console.log(fileInput);
fileInput.addEventListener("change",function(e){
  var files = this.files
  showThumbnail(files)
},false)

fileDiv.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  $(fileInput).show().focus().click().hide();
  e.preventDefault();
},false)

fileDiv.addEventListener("dragenter",function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
},false);

fileDiv.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
},false);

fileDiv.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer;
  var files = dt.files;

  showThumbnail(files)
},false);

function showThumbnail(files){
  for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    var file = files[i]
    var imageType = /image.*/
    if(!file.type.match(imageType)){
      console.log("Not an Image");
      continue;
    }

    var image = document.createElement("img");
    // image.classList.add("")
    var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");
    image.file = file;
    thumbnail.appendChild(image)

    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (function(aImg){
      return function(e){
        aImg.src = e.target.result;
      };
    }(image))
    var ret = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    image.onload= function(){
      ctx.drawImage(image,100,100)
    }
  }
}

$('#thumbnail').on("click", function () {
    $('#thumbnail').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).removeProp('src');
        $('img').replaceWith(selected_photo = $('img').clone(true));
    });
});

          });
```

All advice is appreciated!

Comment: I think there are actually a couple things wrong with this. You are fading out your thumbnail div, which is the container for all of your images. Also, you are removing the source property on that same div (div doesn't use src property, so that is doing nothing), and then when you are doing a replaceWith() on your image, you are selecting all <img> tags, not just the single one that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, you are going to want to do something like the following:

```
$("#thumbnail").on("click", "img", function () {
  var image= $(this);
  image.fadeOut(1000, function () { 
    image.removeProp('src').replaceWith(selected_photo = image.clone(true);
  });
});
```

This will actually fade the image out, remove the source property from the image, and replace it with a clone. I still don't understand the replaceWith() that you have going on, so you may have to tweak that a bit, but the rest should be helpful to you.

Comment: That seems to disable the file upload. I will look into that replaceWith though. Thanks.